# How to compute the $ \lim_{x \to 0+} x \int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\, dt$?

Tags: limits, improper-integrals

I am working out the proof that

$$ \lim_{→0+} x \int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\, dt =1 $$

My attempt is firstly handle the integral parts:

$$ \int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\, dt = \left(-\left(-\text{Si}(x)-\frac{\cos (x)}{x}\right)-\text{Si}(1)-\frac{\cos (1)}{1}\right. $$

where
$$ \text{Si}(z)=\int _0^z\frac{\sin(t)}{t}\, dt $$

Then 
$$x \int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2} = xSi(x) + \cos(x)-xSi(1)-x\cos(1)$$
so,
$$\lim_{→0+} x \int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2} = \lim_{→0+} (xSi(x) + \cos(x)-xSi(1)-x\cos(1))$$

And also,
$$ \lim_{→0+} xSi(1) = 0$$
$$\lim_{→0+}x\cos(1)=0 $$
$$\lim_{→0+}\cos(x)=1 $$
$$\lim_{→0+} xSi(x)=0 ??$$
$$$$

then $$\lim_{→0+} x \int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2} = 1$$

I am uncertain about my proof. Is it correct? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is much simpler to use L'Hospital Rule. Your proof also looks fine.

Comment: see also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928715/find-lim-x-to-0x-int-x1-frac-cos-tt2-dt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler way is to apply the Hopital's rule to and then the [Fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#First_part):
$$\lim_{x→0+} \frac{\int_x^1\frac{\cos(t)}{t^2}\, dt}{1/x}=
\lim_{x→0+} \frac{-\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2}}{-1/x^2}=\lim_{x→0+}\cos(x)=1.$$