# Evaluating $\lim_{x\to0^+}x\int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I've evaluated the below integral, which is one of the problems in the textbook I'm reading from. $$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x\int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}dt
$$
Please see if the method I've used legit. Also, let me know of other methods to solve this.

**Solution**:
$$
\begin{aligned}
f(x) &= x\int_x^1 \frac{\cos t}{t^2}dt \\
&= x\left[-\frac{\cos t}{t}\right]_x^1-x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt \\
&=-x\cos 1+\cos x-x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore
$$
\begin{aligned}
L=\lim_{x\to0^+}x\int_x^1\frac{\cos t}{t^2}dt &= \lim_{x\to0^+}\left(-x\cos 1+\cos x-x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\to0^+}(-x\cos 1)+\lim_{x\to0^+}(\cos x)-\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt\right) \\
&= 0+1-\lim_{x\to0^+}\left(x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
assuming all three limits exist.

Evaluating $$\lim_{x\to0^+}x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt$$
for $0<t\leq1$, we have
$$
0<\frac{\sin t}{t}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}
$$
So, we get
$$
0<\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt<\int_x^1\frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}}=2(1-\sqrt{x}) \text{ where } 0<x<1
$$
Multiplying this inequality by $x$, we get
$$
0<x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt<2x(1-\sqrt{x})
$$
Now taking the required limit, we get
$$
0<\lim_{x\to0^+}x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt<\lim_{x\to0^+}2x(1-\sqrt{x})=0
$$
which means, via Sandwich Theorem,
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}x\int_x^1\frac{\sin t}{t}dt=0
$$

Plugging this result back into the first equation, we get
$$
L=1
$$

Comment: You can use the fact that $$
\frac{{\cos t}}{{t^2 }} = \frac{1}{{t^2 }} + \mathcal{O}(1)
$$ for small $t$.

Comment: What's that $O(1)$?

Comment: [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: Oh okay. But I'm not aware of how to use the Big O notation to arrive at the approximation you've stated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/928731